# Как приклеить один край блока, чтобы он не ездил?

Tags: css3

Всем привет! Мне нужна ваша помощь. То ли я гуглить не умею нормально, но найти ответ на свой вопрос я не смогла. Суть заключается в том, что мне нужно, чтоб там где красная стрелочка, край инпута с кнопкой должен быть приклеен. а там где синяя стрелочка, при выборе определенной категории белый инпут должен уменьшаться или увеличиваться в зависимости от длины категории. а сейчас получается инпут белый становится меньше, но при этом правый край с кнопкой прыгает и расстояние до следующего блока то увеличивается то уменьшается[image: скрин сайта]

Подробнее на Codepen
https://codepen.io/viktoriag373/pen/vYgOjYa

html

```
<div class="page" id="page">
    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="header"> 
        <div class="header-top">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="header-menu menu" > 
                    <ul class="menu__list">
                        <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Компания</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Портфолио</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Проектирование</a></li>
                        <div class="vertical-line"></div>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Ресторанам</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Застройщикам</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Гос.заказчикам</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Таблет-питание</a></li>
                        <div class="vertical-line"></div>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Сервис</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Контакты</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link"><img src="/assets/images/email.svg" alt="" class="menu__icon-mail"> info@stolovay.ru</a></li>
                        <li class="menu__item menu__item-tel">
                            <a href="" class="menu__link">
                                <img src="/assets/images/telephone.svg" alt="" class="menu__icon-tel"> 
                                8 495 790-72-05
                            </a>
                            <div class="menu__contact-us modal-contact-us">
                                <span class="modal-contact-us__close"></span>
                                <div class="modal-contact-us__communication-methods">
                                    <div class="modal-contact-us__number">
                                        <p class="modal-contact-us__tel">8 495 790-72-05</p>
                                        <p class="modal-contact-us__additional-info">Мы принимаем звонки без выходных</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-contact-us__methods">
                                        <p class="modal-contact-us__choice">Выберите способ связи:</p>
                                        <ul class="modal-contact-us__list">
                                            <li class="modal-contact-us__item"><img src="/assets/images/telephone_black.svg" alt="" class="modal-contact-us__social-icon modal-contact-us__icon-tel"><a href="" class="modal-contact-us__link">Мобильный</a></li>
                                            <li class="modal-contact-us__item"><img src="/assets/images/viber.png" alt="" class="modal-contact-us__social-icon"><a href="" class="modal-contact-us__link">Viber</a></li>
                                            <li class="modal-contact-us__item"><img src="/assets/images/telegram.png" alt="" class="modal-contact-us__social-icon"><a href="" class="modal-contact-us__link">Telegram</a></li>
                                            <li class="modal-contact-us__item"><img src="/assets/images/whatsapp.png" alt="" class="modal-contact-us__social-icon"><a href="" class="modal-contact-us__link">Whatsapp</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <form class="modal-contact-us__form">
                                    <p class="modal-contact-us__callback">Обратный звонок:</p>
                                    <p class="modal-contact-us__additional-info">Мы перезвоним в течении часа</p>
                                    <label for="name" class="modal-contact-us__label">Имя:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="modal-contact-us__input" id="name" autocomplete="off">
                                    <label for="tel" class="modal-contact-us__label">Телефон:</label>
                                    <input type="tel" class="modal-contact-us__input" id="tel">
                                    <button type="submit" class="modal-contact-us__button button">Отправить</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>      </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>      </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-center">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header-center__wrap">
                    <div class="header__logo footer__logo logo">
                        
                        <p class="logo__title">Столовая.РУ</p>
                    </div>              <div class="header-search search">
                        <ul class="search-categories">
                            <li class="search-categories__list">
                                <a href="#" class="search-categories__filter">
                                    <span class="search-categories__filter-value">Все</span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="search-categories__subnav">
                                    <p class="search-categories__category">Выбирете категорию:</p>
                                    <li class="search-categories__category-item"><a href="#" class="search-categories__category-link">Все</a></li>
                                    <li class="search-categories__category-item"><a href="#" class="search-categories__category-link">Тепловое</a></li>
                                    <li class="search-categories__category-item"><a href="#" class="search-categories__category-link">Холодильное</a></li>
                                    <li class="search-categories__category-item"><a href="#" class="search-categories__category-link">Электромеханическое</a></li>
                                    <li class="search-categories__category-item"><a href="#" class="search-categories__category-link">Посудомоечное</a></li>
                                    <li class="search-categories__category-item"><a href="#" class="search-categories__category-link">Барное</a></li>
                                    <li class="search-categories__category-item"><a href="#" class="search-categories__category-link">Хлебопекарное</a></li>
                                    <li class="search-categories__category-item"><a href="#" class="search-categories__category-link">Линии раздачи</a></li>
                                    <li class="search-categories__category-item"><a href="#" class="search-categories__category-link">Нейтральное</a></li>
                                    <li class="search-categories__category-item"><a href="#" class="search-categories__category-link">Для фаст фуда</a></li>
                                    <li class="search-categories__category-item"><a href="#" class="search-categories__category-link">Для залов</a></li>
                                    <li class="search-categories__category-item"><a href="#" class="search-categories__category-link">Весовое</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            
                        </ul>
                        <form class="search-query">
                            <input class="search-query__input" type="search">
                            <button type="button" class="search-query__button"></button>    
                        </form>
                        
                        
                    </div>              <div class="header-center__supplier-portal">
                        
                        <p class="header-center__supplier-text">Мы на портале поставщиков</p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="header-center__basket basket">
                        <div class="basket__goods-count">
                            <p class="basket__quantity">12</p>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="basket__sum">
                            <p class="basket__sum-title">Сумма</p>
                            <span class="basket__total-money">150 000 руб</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-bottom">
            <div class="container" style="height: 100px;">
    
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> 
                Qui, omnis sed nihil itaque commodi illo ut aperiam neque nobis nisi tempore, <br> 
                dolor quis pariatur iure culpa delectus voluptatibus saepe nostrum?
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Main -->
    <main class="main">
        <div class="container">
            
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

css

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0-modified | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* make sure to set some focus styles for accessibility */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type=search] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

textarea {
    overflow: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    resize: vertical;
}

/**
 * Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 */
audio,
canvas,
video {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */
audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 7/8/9, Firefox 3, and Safari 4.
 * Known issue: no IE 6 support.
 */
[hidden] {
    display: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct text resizing oddly in IE 6/7 when body `font-size` is set using
 *    `em` units.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */
html {
    font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
 */
a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */
a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 6/7/8/9 and Firefox 3.
 * 2. Improve image quality when scaled in IE 7.
 */
img {
    border: 0;
  /* 1 */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 6/7/8/9, Safari 5, and Opera 11.
 */
figure {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Correct margin displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */
form {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Correct text not wrapping in Firefox 3.
 * 3. Correct alignment displayed oddly in IE 6/7.
 */
legend {
    border: 0;
  /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal;
  /* 2 */
    *margin-left: -7px;
  /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct font size not being inherited in all browsers.
 * 2. Address margins set differently in IE 6/7, Firefox 3+, Safari 5,
 *    and Chrome.
 * 3. Improve appearance and consistency in all browsers.
 */
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
    margin: 0;
  /* 2 */
    vertical-align: baseline;
  /* 3 */
    *vertical-align: middle;
  /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 3+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */
button,
input {
    line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Chrome, Safari 5+, and IE 6+.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox 4+ and Opera.
 */
button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 * 4. Remove inner spacing in IE 7 without affecting normal text inputs.
 *    Known issue: inner spacing remains in IE 6.
 */
button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer;
  /* 3 */
    *overflow: visible;
  /* 4 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */
button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

/**
 * 1. Address box sizing set to content-box in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9.
 * 3. Remove excess padding in IE 7.
 *    Known issue: excess padding remains in IE 6.
 */
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
  /* 2 */
    *height: 13px;
  /* 3 */
    *width: 13px;
  /* 3 */
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
 * on OS X.
 */
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 3+.
 */
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 6/7/8/9.
 * 2. Improve readability and alignment in all browsers.
 */
textarea {
    overflow: auto;
  /* 1 */
    vertical-align: top;
  /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #222;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
    background-color: #f4f2f2;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #121212;
}

body.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Blocks */
.header-top {
    background-color: #00aa4b;
}

.header-center {
    background-color: #e8e7e7;
}

.header-center__wrap {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-center__supplier-portal {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 10%;
    flex: 0 1 10%;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

.header-center__supplier-img {
    width: 3.8rem;
}

.header-center__supplier-text {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #787878;
    line-height: 1.7rem;
}

.header-bottom {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
    max-width: 160rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .container {
        padding-left: 1.5rem;
        padding-right: 1.5rem;
    }
}

.modal-contact-us {
    width: 75.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5rem;
    right: 17rem;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5rem 6rem 6rem 5rem;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-align: top;
    align-items: top;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
}

.modal-contact-us__close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1rem;
    top: 1rem;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.modal-contact-us__close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.modal-contact-us__close:before, .modal-contact-us__close:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    content: ' ';
    height: 30px;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #333;
}

.modal-contact-us__close:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
    transform: rotate(35deg);
}

.modal-contact-us__close:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
    transform: rotate(-35deg);
}

.modal-contact-us__communication-methods {
    -ms-flex: 0 1 44%;
    flex: 0 1 44%;
}

.modal-contact-us__tel {
    font-size: 2.1rem;
    color: #00aa4b;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.modal-contact-us__additional-info {
    color: #787878;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.modal-contact-us__choice {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.modal-contact-us__item {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
}

.modal-contact-us__social-icon {
    width: 2rem;
}

.modal-contact-us__icon-tel {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.modal-contact-us__link {
    color: #000;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    position: relative;
}

.modal-contact-us__link::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0.1rem;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    background-color: #bababa;
}

.modal-contact-us__link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.modal-contact-us__link:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}

.modal-contact-us__form {
    -ms-flex: 0 1 42%;
    flex: 0 1 42%;
}

.modal-contact-us__callback {
    font-size: 2.1rem;
    line-height: 3.4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.modal-contact-us__label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.modal-contact-us__input {
    margin-left: 0.1rem;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bababa;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

.modal-contact-us__input:focus {
    transition: 0.5s;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffaf2d;
}

.button {
    background-color: #ffaf2d;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 2.2rem;
    padding: 1.3rem 2.5rem;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #ffa30e;
    transition: 0.7s;
}

.menu__list {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu__link {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1.2rem 2rem 1.2rem 2rem;
    position: relative;
}

.menu__link:hover {
    background: #33bb6f;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu__item-tel:hover .modal-contact-us {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.menu__icon-mail {
    width: 2rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.menu__icon-tel {
    width: 2rem;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.vertical-line {
    content: '';
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 0.1rem;
    background: #33bb6f;
    margin: 1.2rem 0;
}

.header__logo {
    margin: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 16%;
    flex: 0 1 16%;
}

.logo {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo__img {
    width: 4rem;
}

.logo__title {
    font-size: 3.3rem;
    margin-left: 0.8rem;
}

.header-search {
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.search {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 56%;
    flex: 0 1 56%;
}

.search-categories__list {
    position: relative;
}

.search-categories__filter {
    padding: 0.85rem 0.5rem 0.95rem 1.5rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
  /* Запрещаем перенос строк */
    color: #777;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 0.7rem 0 0 0.7rem;
    margin-right: 0.2rem;
}

.search-categories__filter:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.search-categories__filter-value {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.search-categories__subnav {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3.4rem;
    left: 0.2rem;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 1.5rem 3.5rem 4rem 1.5rem;
}

.search-categories__subnav--visible {
    display: block;
}

.search-categories__category {
    color: #777;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.search-categories__category-item {
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
}

.search-categories__category-item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.search-categories__category-link {
    color: #343434;
}

.search-categories__category-link:hover {
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00aa4b;
}

.search-query {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 90%;
    flex: 0 1 90%;
}

.search-query__input {
    -ms-flex: 0 1 100%;
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.9rem 2.5rem 0.9rem;
}

.search-query__button {
    background-color: #ffaf2d;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.82rem 1.3rem 0.84rem 1.3rem;
    border-radius: 0 0.7rem 0.7rem 0;
}

.basket {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 9%;
    flex: 0 1 9%;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
  /* Запрещаем перенос строк */
    cursor: pointer;
}

.basket:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.6s;
    background-color: #ffaf2d;
}

.basket:hover .basket__quantity,
    .basket:hover .basket__sum-title,
    .basket:hover .basket__total-money {
    color: #fff;
}

.basket__goods-count {
    position: relative;
}

.basket__quantity {
    color: #ffaf2d;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.3rem;
    left: 1.2rem;
}

.basket__icon {
    width: 3rem;
}

.basket__sum {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.basket__sum-title {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #787878;
    line-height: 1rem;
}

.basket__total-money {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #171717;
}
```

js

```
const searchCategoriesFilter = document.querySelector(".search-categories__filter");
const searchCategoriesSubnav = document.querySelector(".search-categories__subnav");
const searchCategoriesCategoryItem = document.querySelectorAll(".search-categories__category-item");
const searchCategoriesFilterValue = document.querySelector(".search-categories__filter-value");

function categoriesSubnavToggle() {
    searchCategoriesSubnav.classList.toggle("search-categories__subnav--visible");
}

function categoriesSubnavClose() {
    searchCategoriesSubnav.classList.remove("search-categories__subnav--visible");
}

function onCategoryClick(event) {
    searchCategoriesFilterValue.innerText = event.target.innerText;
    categoriesSubnavClose();
}


searchCategoriesFilter.onclick = categoriesSubnavToggle;

for (let index = 0; index < searchCategoriesCategoryItem.length; index++) {
    searchCategoriesCategoryItem[index].onclick = onCategoryClick;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте в css такие изменения:

```
.search-query {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
```

Comment: эта выпадашка не встаёт плотно к оранжевому блоку:  https://ibb.co/6HpxsY8

Comment: Как я понял она и не должна. Проблема в том, что при изменении ширины "селекта" гуляет ширина всего поискового блока. могу конечно ошибаться.

Comment: а может вы  правы ...+

Comment: @MaximLensky Выпадашка прилепать не должна. Как написал Bear Vorkuta, проблема в том что гуляет ширина всего поискового блока. а нужно чтоб оранжевй конец всегда стоял на одном месте, а белый инпут слева уменьшался, когда увеличивается категория. Изменения для .search-query помогли

Comment: @ВикторияГладышева да я же согласился с ним и по этому + поставил